# EV3 Gyro sensor is not working

Tags: ev3, gyro

I started using the EV3 Gyro for the first time in a few months, and it's not working. When I rotate the robot the output shown in the EV3-G port view stays at zero. In the rare case it registers some input, it will show for a split second and immediately reset to zero. In the on-brick port view, and when output from the block, it shows as "----". Switching ports doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you also try a different cable in addition to different ports?

Comment: Actually I didnt, I will try it

Comment: It works after swapping cables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If other sensors work on the EV3, the EV3 is OK. If swapping cables does not help, then the sensor is probably defective. If you contact LEGO customer service, they will probably replace it if it is defective.

Comment: And make sure you use ports 1-4 and turn the gyro in every direction possible and see if it detects it.